# Why does this code generate the compiler error C2227?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, compiler-errors, static-members

I'm working on integrating my current game engine with the irrKlang sound engine, and am dealing with a persistent error.  Simplified:

fsCore.h

```
class fsEngine
{
public:
    static fsEngine *getInstance();
    static void release();
    ;
private:
    static fsEngine *instance;
    static fsBool exists;
    irrklang::ISoundEngine *soundEngine;
};
```

fsCore.cpp

```
#include "fsCore.h"
void fsEngine::release()
{
    exists = false;
    delete instance;
    soundEngine->drop(); //C2227
};
```

The engine is being declared correctly, and the singleton is performing as expected.  Any ideas?

Comment: If `release()` is static, how can it access `soundEngine`, which is an *instance* member?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explanation of C2227 can be found here: [Compiler Error C2227](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z8wd049%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

When the compiler gets to this line:

```
soundEngine->drop(); //C2227
```

it tells you that `soundEngine` must be pointer to class / struct / union in order to call `drop()` on it. The actual problem here is that you're trying to access the non-static data member from static function.

Also note that `delete` doesn't changes the value of pointer itself, so after this line is executed:

```
delete instance;
```

the value of `instance` is still set to the same address, this pointer has became invalid (*dangling*). It is a good practice to assign `NULL` to the pointer after you `delete` it:

```
delete instance;
instance = NULL;
```

Comment: Ah thank you.  Does that mean I can't access static variables from a non-static function? LNK2001.

Comment: @Catsup: Accessing static members from a non-static member function is perfectly OK.

Comment: the link error was from attempting to access the static variable from outside the file it was created in.